# For-loop looping too often because it's not exiting properly (performance)

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, break

I currently have an array with a size of one million, and a method that parses new objects (each one with a key and value) or overwrites an object in case a new object has an already existing key. The thing is that the loop for the overwriting part is taking an extremely long time with an array this big because it is not exiting properly. For every element it parses it checks every index, so for a thousand elements to parse it would do a billion checks, which is obviously not desired behaviour.

```
private const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000000;
private Paar[] pArr = new Paar[ARRAY_SIZE];

    public void Put(string key, object value)
    {
        bool wasReplaced = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < pArr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (pArr[i] != null && pArr[i].key == key)
            {
                pArr[i] = new Paar(key, value);
                wasReplaced = true;
            }
        }
        if (wasReplaced == false)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pArr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (pArr[i] == null)
                {
                    pArr[i] = new Paar(key, value);
                    break;
                }
                else if (i >= pArr.Length)
                {
                    throw new Exception("All slots full");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: Note that I am using two loops to prevent the overwriting function from being able to parse an object with a duplicate key and new value into an empty index if there happens to be one before the duplicate key's index (for example if I set one or more random indexes to null).

```
string keyparse = "Key";
string valueparse = "Value";
Random rnd = new Random();

int wdh = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < wdh; i++)
{
    myMap.Put(keyparse + rnd.Next(1, 10000), valueparse + rnd.Next(1, 10000));
}
```

I tried to make the first part of the function add 1 to an int and break if the int reaches the number of elements parsed, but it does not seem to function properly, and neither does it affect the time taken by the function.

```
        bool wasReplaced = false;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < pArr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (pArr[i] != null)
            {
                count += 1;

                if (pArr[i] != null && pArr[i].key == key)
                {
                    pArr[i] = new Paar(key, value);
                    count += 1;
                    break;
                }

                else if (count == 1000)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
       }
```

I don't really know why this wouldn't work or how else I could approach this, so I'm kind of stuck here... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of an array of key-value pairs? It is much better optimized for this kind of operation.

Comment: Just practice. I'm pretty new to coding so I'm trying out loads of different stuff, and I was told to try it this way because it'd be good practice since it's relatively unconventional. I agree that a dictionary would be simpler, but for now I'd like to stick with an array :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by declaring an instance variable and a local variable which are then to be compared. I also fixed a logical error I made (now the second loop counts properly and the first loop doesn't count anymore if it overwrites something but instead returns).
The method still functions the same but now runs much more efficiently (took 7 seconds for 5kk parses compared to the previous 12 seconds for 1k parses!).

```
    int _objectCount = 0;
    public void Put(string key, object value)
    {                          
        int localCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pArr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (pArr[i] != null)
            {
                localCount++;

                if (pArr[i].key == key)
                { 
                    pArr[i] = new Paar(key, value); 
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (localCount == _objectCount)
            {
                return;
            }
        }                      
        for (int i = 0; i < pArr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (pArr[i] == null)
            { 
                pArr[i] = new Paar(key, value);
                _objectCount++;
                return;
            }

            else if (i >= pArr.Length)
            {
                throw new Exception("All slots full");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Dictionary - but you write it's for practice ...

In that case:

Speedup 1: (Assuming your key is unique!)

```
for (int i = 0; i < pArr.Length; i++)
 {
     if (pArr[i] != null && pArr[i].key == key)
     {
         pArr[i] = new Paar(key, value);
 //         wasReplaced = true; 
         return;
     }
 }
```

Speedup 2: When traversing in the first for-loop, save the first position of an empty space. Then you can use that instantly and only have to iterate the array once.

```
int empty = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < pArr.Length; i++)
{
    if (pArr[i] != null )
    {
        if (pArr[i].key == key)
        {
            pArr[i] = new Paar(key, value);
            return;
        }
    }
    else if( empty < 0 )
    {
        empty = i;
    }
}

if( pArr >= 0 )
    pArr[empty] = new Paar(key,value);
else // Array has been fully traversed without match and without empty space
    throw new Exception("All slots full");
```

Speedup 3: You could keep track of the highest index used, so you can break the for-loop early.

Mind that these measures are only to speed up that part. I did not take into account many other considerations and possible techniques like hashing, thread-safety, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things may done here-

1. A minor improvement will be break your loop when you set `wasReplaced = true`

   ```
   if (pArr[i] != null && pArr[i].key == key)
   {
       pArr[i] = new Paar(key, value);
       wasReplaced = true;
       break;
   }
   ```

   But it is not a good solution
2. Another solution is you may use TPL (Task Parallel Library), to use multithread and multicore. There is a `ParallelForEach()` loop there.
3. Another solution is use `Dictionary<string, string>` to store your values, instead of using an array. `Dictionary<>` uses hash map, you will get a better performance.
4. If you still want to use your own implementation with array, then try to use hashing or heap algorithm to store your data. By using hashing or heap you can store/get/update data by `O(log(n))` time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<Paar> pArr = new list<Paar>();

public void Put(string key, object value)
{

(from p in pArr 
 where p!= null && p.key!=key select p).ToList()
                                        .ForEach(x => x.key== key, x.Value==value);

}
```

Try with Linq Query

Answer (score 0):

As written in a comment, I suggest you to use Dictionary instead of Paar class, so you can do something like:

```
int ARRAY_SIZE= 100000;
Dictionary<string, object> pArr = new Dictionary<string, object>()

public void Put(string key, string object)
{
   if(pArr.ContainsKey(key))
      pArr[key] = value;
   else 
   {
      if(pArr.Count() >= ARRAY_SIZE)
         throw new Exception("All slots full");

      pArr.Add(key, value)
   }
}
```

If you need to use Paar class, you can use the .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value) to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't want to use a dictionary and there may be a match anywhere within the array, then the best you can do is search the whole array until you find a match, and capture the index of the first `null` item along the way (for an insertion point if a match is not found):

```
public static void Put(string key, object value)
{
    int insertionIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < pArr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pArr[i] != null)
        {
            if (pArr[i].Key == key)
            {
                insertionIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (insertionIndex < 0)
        {
            insertionIndex = i;
        }
    }

    if (insertionIndex < 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("All slots full");
    }
    else
    {
        pArr[insertionIndex] = new Paar(key, value);
    }
}
```